# Generations of a counting sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, natural-numbers

A counting sequence is a sequence whose terms are also sequences. To be specific, its terms are sequences of natural numbers. [And if you are familiar with the look and say sequence, its very similar to it.]

Here is an example.
$$ T_1:  (5,1,2)$$
$$ T_2: (1,1,1,2,1,5)$$
$$ T_3:  (4,1,1,2,1,5)$$
   and so on...
where,
$$T_n=n^{th} term$$ 
NOTICE that the terms are created by counting the natural numbers inside it and ordering them as you list them in the next term.

Here is my problem:
I want to make a proof of the following statement.

**If the 1st term of the sequence is $$(m,m+1)$$, where $m\ge7$, then its $(m+1)^{th}$ term is $(m,1,1,2,1,3,...,1,m+1)$.**

An example for this statement is:
 $ T_1:  (7,8)$

$ T_2:  (1,7,1,8)$

$ T_3:  (2,1,1,7,1,8)$

$ T_4:  (3,1,1,2,1,7,1,8)$

$ T_5:  (4,1,1,2,1,3,1,7,1,8)$

$ T_6:  (5,1,1,2,1,3,1,4,1,7,1,8)$

$ T_7:  (6,1,1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1,7,1,8)$

$ T_8:  (7,1,1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1,6,1,7,1,8)$
which shows that this example satisfies that statement.

Any help is much appreciated. I have tried using induction on it but I'm having trouble with the induction hypothesis part.

Comment: please excuse the way i have made this question. i still dont know mathjax. if someone could translate it, it would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

If $T_1:(m,m+1)$, clearly, $T_2: (1,m,1,m+1)$, and $T_3: (2,1,1,m,1,m+1)$. So, $T_3$ follows the pattern $T_{n}:(\underbrace{n-1,1}, \underbrace{1,2},\underbrace{1,3},\ldots,\underbrace{1,n-2},\underbrace{1,m},\underbrace{1,m+1})$.

Let us assume that the pattern holds for $n\leq m$, so that $n-1$ and $m$ are distinct. Here, the number 1 is repeated $n-2+2=n$; the numbers $2,3,\ldots,n-1$ are repeated once; the numbers $m,m+1$ are repeated once. Thus,
\begin{equation}
T_{n+1}:(n,1,1,2,1,3\ldots,1,n-1,1,m,1,m+1).
\end{equation}
Hence, by induction, we prove that $T_{n}:(n-1,1,1,2,1,3,\ldots,1,n-2,1,m,1,m+1)$, for $n\leq m+1$. Finally, substituting $n=m+1$, we get the deisred result.

Comment: Can you make a proof that does not depend on n? I need a proof that only depends on (m,m+1) and (m,1,1,2,...,1,m+1) because i will also want to prove a similar statement where the pattern with n, the n-1 and n-2 you have used, does not exist.

Comment: Now, commenting on your proof, this induction is done on the variable n which is on the generation of the terms. So you have proved that all the generated terms after the nth term follows the desired form. But the original problem is interested on the relationship between the variable m in the 1st term AND its (m+1)th term.

Comment: In other words, i want to prove that when the first term is (7,8) then its (m+1)th term follows the form, if 1st term is (8,9) then it follows the form, and so on where the variable m in (m,m+1) is greater than or equal to 7.

Comment: My proof is for a general m>2. You can plug your favorite m, and the proof works! In fact, I have proved more things than what you have asked for.

Comment: What are those additional things?

Comment: Now lets see how your proof works on the (m+1)th term of the first term fo the form (m,m+1,m+2,m+3).

Comment: That's a different problem. I have worked it out for the case when the first term is (m,m+1). The proof gives the form of Tn for n<=m+1, not just (m+1) terms. For a sequence which starts from a different first term, try to follow a similar technique: Formulate Tn and use induction on n.

Comment: I cannot understand what you mean in this statement.The proof gives the form of Tn for n<=m+1, not just (m+1) terms.

Comment: Could you pls elaborate.

Comment: We use induction over n, instead of m. So, we get the form of the sequence for $n<=m+1$. However, the question is about the special case of $n=m+1$ only. The reason why we have to use induction over n is that it is easy to relate the consecutive terms of the sequence Tn.